# pandas tables to html, horizontal with two columns

Tags: python, html, pandas, web, html-table

I am trying to turn a pandas table into a horizontal html table with two columns. The original table has one row and it can be generated using the python code below.

```
df_dict = {}
for i in range(10):
    col = 'col:' + str(i)
    val = 'val:'+ str(i)
    df_dict.update({col:val})
    
df = pd.DataFrame([df_dict])
```

I want the resulting html table to have the format of the table shown in the link below. Does anybody have any ideas on how to accomplish this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvvAC.png

Comment: Try transposing your data frame like this: `df = df.transpose()`

Answer (score 1):

First let's transpose and reset the index:

```
df = df.T.reset_index()
```

Now let's generate the HTML table:

```
pd.concat([df.iloc[:5, ], df.iloc[5:, ].reset_index()], axis=1).drop(columns=['level_0']).to_html()
```